# Create unique chart for each sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, loops, figure, vba

I am attempting to create a chart in each sheet of my workbook using VBA. I have used code gleaned from the net. The closest I came to success was ending up with 28 of the same chart on the first sheet.

Here is that code where each sheet has the data in the specified location

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
  Dim WS_Count As Integer
  Dim I As Integer

  ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
  ' workbook.
  WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

  ' Begin the loop.
  For I = 1 To WS_Count
    ActiveSheet.Range("P2:AB2153").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$P$2:$AB$2153")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0.5
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft 393.75
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop -31243.1249606299

    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name
  Next I
End Sub
```

---

You'll notice that I moved the shape after it is created. This was because the very first time they were all located at the bottom of a very long sheet

I then tried  adding

```
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet

For Each sheet In Sheets
```

and changing `ActiveSheet to thisSheet`

No success.

I have over 100 sheets in many workbooks
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Compiled but not tested:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

    Dim WS As Worksheet, co As Object

    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        Set co = WS.Shapes.AddChart()

        ActiveSheet.Range("P2:AB2153").Select

        'adjust to suit...
        co.Top = 100
        co.Left = 100
        co.Width = 300
        co.Height = 250

        With co.Chart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
            .SetSourceData Source:=WS.Range("$P$2:$AB$2153")
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0.5
        End With

        Debug.Print "Processed: " & WS.Name

    Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll give that a try as well

Answer (score 0):

I came up with my own answer and added some other other stuff

---

:

Sub WorksheetLoopchart()

```
     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count

    Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("P2:AB2153").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$P$2:$AB$2153")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0.1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Wavelength (nm)"
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Absolute Reflectance"
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)

        ' Insert your code here.
        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

     Next I

  End Sub
```

The index + 1 did the trick